# HashMaps with String keys as animation keys okay?

Tags: libgdx, performance

In my project I use an ECS system. I have a `SpriteComponent` that contains a map of animations.

```java
public class SpriteComponent implements Component {
    public HashMap<String, Animation<TextureRegion>> animations = new HashMap<>();
    public Animation<TextureRegion> currentAnimationToRender;
}
```

The key is made up of strings because I manage the sprites in my assets folder according to a specific structure.

Structure:

```
"<path_prefix>/<object_name>/<state>/<object_name>_<state>_<direction>"
```

Example:

```
"figures/player/block/player_moving_ne"
```

In each loop run, I build a string in my animation system (e.g. if the player moves north, then append "moving" and "n") and thus get a corresponding key to load and render the animation from the map.

```java
 public void update(float deltaTime) {
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            SpriteComponent spriteComponent = spriteComponentMapper.get(entity);
            MovingComponent movingComponent = movingComponentMapper.get(entity);
            // ... more neccessary components for e.g. attacking ...


            String designator = // ...
            // ...
            if(movingComponent.isMoving && movingComponent.up) {
                designator += designator + "_moving_n"
            } else if(movingComponent.isMoving && movingComponent.right) {
                designator += designator + "_moving_e"
            }
            //...

            spriteComponent.currentAnimationToRender = animations.get(designator);

        }
 }
```

My concern now is that this process might perform poorly later on as the game gets more complex. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: I'd recommend not asking us for permission to use code that works. If this code is not suitable for your needs, it won't be us who tells you this (and it's not out opinion that matters): it will be the profiler. Make an artificial test where you have many objects in your scene using this all at once, and measure the combined impact. If it's within your performance budget, then it doesn't matter if a stranger on the Internet didn't like it. If it's outside your performance budget, then it doesn't matter if the Internet strangers all said it was fine — you'd still have a problem. So: profile.

Comment: If you want open-ended feedback on code that works, but that you want to make faster, leaner, or more maintainable, there's a dedicated [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for that.